# CSV Stream Response Django

Tags: python, django, csv, nginx, gunicorn

I'm generating a csv file from query the database and want to return the file to the User to download. The file is corrupted, as if the download had been interrupted before completion. The code used is below:

```
class Echo(object):
    def write(self, value):
        return value
pseudo_buffer = Echo()
csv_data = []
for d in pesquisa:
    csv_data.append([d[h] for h in data])
writer = csv.writer(pseudo_buffer)
response = StreamingHttpResponse((writer.writerow(row) for row in csv_data),
content_type="text/csv")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'
return response
```

I am using Django 1.8.9 + Gunicorn + Nginx

If I use the django test server got the following error:

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: why not post the full code? For example where does pesquisa or data come from?

Comment: I will update the code, but the problem is not in the data, the data are a dictionaries list. The file is generated, but it to around line 120, so the file gets corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `StreamingHttpResponse`:

```
csv_data = []
for d in pesquisa:
    csv_data.append([d[h] for h in data])

response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
writer = csv.writer(response)
writer.writerows(csv_data)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'

return response
```

Comment: The problem remains, the file is 50,000 lines, but the system to generate around line 120. @serg

Comment: Probably some Gunicorn setting then, nginx+uwsgi+django returns all lines with the code above.